# Roman to Numeral calculator with "for i in X"

Tags: python, function, converters, calculator

i tried to build a calculator that easily convert Roman to Numeral
can somebody tell me how can i choose all the 2 characters words to be in high priority?

** roman is a string

```
#Roman Numeral calculator

def RomanToDecimal(roman):
DecimalValue=0
for i in roman:
    if i == "CM":
        DecimalValue += 900
    if i == "IV":
        DecimalValue += 4
    if i == "IX":
        DecimalValue += 9
    if i == "XL":
        DecimalValue += 40
    if i == "XC":
        DecimalValue += 90
    if i == "CD":
        DecimalValue += 400
    elif i in roman:
        if i == "I":
            DecimalValue += 1
        if i == "V":
            DecimalValue += 5
        if i == "X":
            DecimalValue += 10
        if i == "L":
            DecimalValue += 50
        if i == "C":
            DecimalValue += 100
        if i == "D":
            DecimalValue += 500
        if i == "M":
            DecimalValue += 1000

return DecimalValue
```

and i'm new here so please try to answer me with patience

Comment: Leaving aside the technique for a moment, what kind of input is `roman`? A string? If so, `i` will always be a single character and you'll never hit any of your two-letter words.

Comment: yes, roman is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are [more efficient ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820037/roman-to-numeral-calculator-with-for-i-in-x/34820229#34820229) to do this, this follows the style of your own code so hopefully will be easier to follow.

The main change is to replace the `for` loop with a `while` loop and a manual counter. This makes it possible to skip ahead two steps when we encounter one of our double-chars. Next we extract the characters and inspect them — *first* looking two chars ahead, *next* looking individually. If we find a match at 2 chars long we step forward 2 (past them) and restart the loop:

```
def RomanToDecimal(roman):
    DecimalValue=0 
    i = 0 # Position in string

    while i < len(roman):

        # Test for 2 char first    
        if i < len(roman)-1: # Make sure we're not on the last letter
            # Get current + next letters
            s = roman[i:i+2] 
            add = False

            if s == "CM":
                add = 900
            elif s == "IV":
                add = 4
            elif s == "IX":
                add = 9
            elif s == "XL":
                add = 40
            elif s == "XC":
                add = 90
            elif s == "CD":
                add = 400

            if add: # We've found a match
                i += 2 # Step 2
                DecimalValue += add # Add the value
                continue # Next loop

        # If we get here the 2 character match failed
        # Single char match
        s = roman[i] 

        if s == "I":
            DecimalValue += 1
        elif s == "V":
            DecimalValue += 5
        elif s == "X":
            DecimalValue += 10
        elif s == "L":
            DecimalValue += 50
        elif s == "C":
            DecimalValue += 100
        elif s == "D":
            DecimalValue += 500
        elif s == "M":
            DecimalValue += 1000

        i += 1

    return DecimalValue

RomanToDecimal('XIXIX')
28
```

It should be noted that the above is not *really* a valid Roman numeral string (28 is correctly represented by XXVIII), but hopefully that's not a problem!

Let me know if the code is unclear anywhere and I will add more comments.

Comment: Thank you so much, Martin!! :] you made me day

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend first translating roman into arabic one by one, multiply some of them by -1 and finally just sum:

```
roman = 'MMXIV'
D = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
tmp = [D[x] for x in roman]
for i in range(len(tmp) - 1):
    if tmp[i + 1] > tmp[i]:
        tmp[i] *= -1
print(sum(tmp))
```

Comment: Elegant, but perhaps a bit complicated?

Comment: i'm a beginner sorry

Comment: @Lucia try to ask, I'm happy to explain

Answer (score 0):

Classic questions have classic answers in Rosetta Code: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Decode#Python

```
_rdecode = dict(zip('MDCLXVI', (1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1)))

def decode( roman ):
    result = 0
    for r, r1 in zip(roman, roman[1:]):
        rd, rd1 = _rdecode[r], _rdecode[r1]
        result += -rd if rd < rd1 else rd
    return result + _rdecode[roman[-1]]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for r in 'MCMXC MMVIII MDCLXVI'.split():
        print( r, decode(r) )
```